# Customize ActionBar, only some items custom views

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-relativelayout

I've read about the ActionBar and tried some stuff. I've come to the point where I replace the ActionBar with a custom view like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_timer);
```

but some of the icons are too big, and it's not really how I want it to be, there is a huge padding to the right (to the options menu icon).

So this is what my actionbar_timer layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/de.myapp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="#000"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_actionbar_back" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_moon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_actionbar_moon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionbar_timer"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_actionbar_clock" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionbar_back"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_actionbar_something" />

    <de.myapp.views.TextViewPlus
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionbar_moon"
        android:gravity="center|center"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:customFont="roboto_regular.ttf" />

    <View
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I've set alignParentRight="true" at the right-most elements of my layout, but there still is a big gap between the views and the options menu icon.

Is there a way to reduce this gap? Also, I had to "recreate" the blue line on bottom of the ActionBar with the View-stub at the end of the layout. How can I avoid this? I'm using ActionBarSherlock, by the way.